# How do I plot a line that wraps around the x-axis in matplotlib and python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot prices to the day of the year.

So, the x-axis is a number from 0 to 365/366, but not all periods or cycles start and end in the same calendar year.

Some periods or cycles may start in the previous calendar year, and some may end in the following year.

I have figured out how to 'wrap around' using hline to show when the cycles occur during the year, but can not use this approach with the prices since they fluctuate, and I need to use df.plot() for the prices.

As you can see by the plot shown, the black line (df2) ends in the following calendar year, but it draws a line between the price at 31 Dec to the price at 1 Jan, but I do not want this. I want it to be similar to the middle graph where the orange line stops at the end, and starts again at the beginning of the year.

[Graph showing hline() and plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqjTp.png)

Here's the code used to make the plots, but does not give the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## make sample dataframes
cycle_data = {'Period':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'], 'Start':[338,78,190,273], 'End':[117,166,299,17]}
normal_prices = {'Calendar Day':[150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170],
                 'Price':[4.1,4.3,3.9,2.5,4.5,4.6,4.2,4.0,3.9,3.8,3.7,3.8,3.9,4.0,3.9,3.5,3.2,4.1,4.4,4.5,3.9]}
abnormal_prices = {'Calendar Day':[350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'Price':[4.6,4.2,4.0,3.9,3.8,3.7,4.1,4.3,3.9,3.5,4.5,3.9,3.85,3.7,3.6,3.5,3.3,3.3,3.5,3.6,4.0,3.9,4.1,4.2,4.4,4.6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(cycle_data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(normal_prices)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(abnormal_prices)


##
# set up the graph
##
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)

axs[0].set_title('Horizontal Line and Plot to Calendar Day', fontdict = {'fontsize' : 12}) # must be after axs to be seen.  
axs[1].set_xlim([-5,370])   # set x-axis limits to be number of days in calendar year with spacer of 5 days on either side for ease of viewing
axs[2].set_xlim([-5,370])   # set x-axis limits to be number of days in calendar year with spacer of 5 days on either side for ease of viewing

plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,365,13)[:-1], ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Dec')) ## set the x axis to show the month names instead of day numbers

##
#   make legend
##
axs[0].tick_params (left = False, bottom = False,labelleft = False, labelbottom = False)

axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Cycle starts and ends in same year', color='blue')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Cycle starts and ends in different calendar year', color='orange')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Price Range starts and ends in same year', color='purple')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Price Range starts and ends in different calendar year', color='black')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].legend(title = 'Legend',title_fontsize = 12, fontsize = 8, ncol=1, loc = 'upper center')


##
#   Graph Period time frames
#
#       - blue line shows cycles that start and end in same calendar year
#       - orange lines show cycles that either start in a previous calendar year, or end in the following calendar year.
##
axs[1].tick_params (bottom = False,labelbottom = False)

axs[1].axvline(0,-1,len(df['Period']),color='grey', label = 'Calendar Year Start / End',linewidth = 2, zorder = 1)   # put vertical line at Day 0 of calendar year
axs[1].axvline(365,-1,len(df['Period']),color='grey', linewidth = 2, zorder = 1) # put vertical line at Day 365 of calendar year


axs[1].scatter(df['Start'],df['Period'],color = 'green', label = 'Cycle Start', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)  # Cycle start
axs[1].scatter(df['End'],df['Period'],color = 'red', label = 'Cycle End', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)    # Cycle End

for i in range(len(df)):#   Draw horizontal line(s) to show the cycle for each period / row in dataframe.

    ##  Option 1: Draw line between start and end points if start and end dates are in same calendar year (green marker to left of red).
    if df.loc[i,'Start'] < df.loc[i,'End']:
        axs[1].hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=df.loc[i,'Start'], xmax=df.loc[i,'End'], color='blue', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0) 
         
    ##  Option 2: Draw 2 lines if the start or end dates are not in the same calendar year (red marker to left of green).
    else:
        axs[1].hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=df.loc[i,'Start'], xmax=365, color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # end date is in next calendar year
        axs[1].hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=0, xmax=df.loc[i,'End'], color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # start date is in previous calendar year


##
#   plot the price data
#
#       - purple line shows cycles that start and end in same calendar year
#       - black lines show cycles that either start in a previous calendar year, or end in the following calendar year.
##

axs[2].axvline(0,-1,len(df1),color='grey', label = 'Calendar Year Start / End',linewidth = 2, zorder = 1)   # put vertical line at Day 0 of calendar year
axs[2].axvline(365,-1,len(df1),color='grey', linewidth = 2, zorder = 1) # put vertical line at Day 365 of calendar year


axs[2].plot(df1['Calendar Day'], df1['Price'], color='purple', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # plots normally

axs[2].plot(df2['Calendar Day'], df2['Price'], color='black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # should wrap around, but does not


plt.show()
```

I can use the following block to chart the price on each day, but using ax.scatter() does not 'connect the dots' and the price movement is not readily apparent like it is if I use ax.plot().

```
if df2['Calendar Day'].iloc[0] < df2['Calendar Day'].iloc[-1]:  # 'normal' where start and end are in same calendar year
    
    axs[2].plot(df2['Calendar Day'], df2['Price'], color='black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # 
    
else:
    
    axs[2].scatter(df2['Calendar Day'],df2['Price'],color = 'black', marker = ',',s = 1, zorder = 2) # 'abnormal' where start and end are in different calendar years
```

Is there a way to split the ax.plot() so that it does not draw the connecting line from Day 365 back to Day 0 in the year?

[Output showing Prices using scatter()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm2F0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, AFAIK, to solve this you need to split your dataframe before plotting. If the date sequences were increasing (365, 366, 367), this could be done with a simple mask, something like

```
axs[2].plot(df2[df2['Calendar Day'] <= 365], ... # before
axs[2].plot(df2[df2['Calendar Day'] > 365] - 365, ... # after
```

Since your values go back to 1 after 365, then it's a matter of finding that spot. I'm very rusty with pandas, there's certainly a more elegant way of doing this, but I used a loop.

```py
previous = None
point = None
for i, line in df2.iterrows():
    if not previous:
        previous = line['Calendar Day']
        continue
    if line['Calendar Day'] < previous:
        point = i
        break
    else:
        previous = line['Calendar Day']

axs[2].plot(df1['Calendar Day'], df1['Price'], color='purple', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # plots normally
axs[2].plot(df2['Calendar Day'][:point], df2['Price'][:point], color='black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # should wrap around, but does not
axs[2].plot(df2['Calendar Day'][point:], df2['Price'][point:], color='black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # should wrap around, but does not

plt.show()
```

This splits the plot command into two, one for each region, removing that ugly connecting line.

Comment: Thanks. I was just about to post an answer myself based on very much the same logic. Looped through df2, found the point where it split and assigned a left_df and right_df based on the split point and did 2 plots as you did. Does the trick, but not quite as elegantly as yours.

Comment: Great that you found a solution by yourself! Yeah, the logic is the same. I have the impression there's a pandas method to do what you need, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I lied. While my approach works for the sample date, it fell down during the real-world application. Your approach  works with all my data, so I' m using it in lieu of my attempt.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to achieve the result, but not necessarily answer the question if there is a native way to split a plot() in matplotlib.

[What chart should actually look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFHDX.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## make sample dataframes
cycle_data = {'Period':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'], 'Start':[338,78,190,273], 'End':[117,166,299,17]}
normal_prices = {'Calendar Day':[150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170],
                 'Price':[4.1,4.3,3.9,2.5,4.5,4.6,4.2,4.0,3.9,3.8,3.7,3.8,3.9,4.0,3.9,3.5,3.2,4.1,4.4,4.5,3.9]}
abnormal_prices = {'Calendar Day':[350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'Price':[4.6,4.2,4.0,3.9,3.8,3.7,4.1,4.3,3.9,3.5,4.5,3.9,3.85,3.7,3.6,3.5,3.3,3.3,3.5,3.6,4.0,3.9,4.1,4.2,4.4,4.6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(cycle_data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(normal_prices)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(abnormal_prices)


##
# set up the graph
##
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)

axs[0].set_title('Horizontal Line and Plot to Calendar Day', fontdict = {'fontsize' : 12}) # must be after axs to be seen.  
axs[1].set_xlim([-5,370])   # set x-axis limits to be number of days in calendar year with spacer of 5 days on either side for ease of viewing
axs[2].set_xlim([-5,370])   # set x-axis limits to be number of days in calendar year with spacer of 5 days on either side for ease of viewing

plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,365,13)[:-1], ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Dec')) ## set the x axis to show the month names instead of day numbers

##
#   make legend
##
axs[0].tick_params (left = False, bottom = False,labelleft = False, labelbottom = False)

axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Cycle starts and ends in same year', color='blue')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Cycle starts and ends in different calendar year', color='orange')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Price Range starts and ends in same year', color='purple')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Price Range starts and ends in different calendar year', color='black')  # just for legend only.
axs[0].legend(title = 'Legend',title_fontsize = 12, fontsize = 8, ncol=1, loc = 'upper center')


##
#   Graph Period time frames
#
#       - blue line shows cycles that start and end in same calendar year
#       - orange lines show cycles that either start in a previous calendar year, or end in the following calendar year.
##
axs[1].tick_params (bottom = False,labelbottom = False)

axs[1].axvline(0,-1,len(df), color='grey', label = 'Calendar Year Start / End',linewidth = 2, zorder = 1)   # put vertical line at Day 0 of calendar year
axs[1].axvline(365,-1,len(df), color='grey', linewidth = 2, zorder = 1) # put vertical line at Day 365 of calendar year

axs[1].scatter(df['Start'],df['Period'],color = 'green', label = 'Cycle Start', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)  # Cycle start
axs[1].scatter(df['End'],df['Period'],color = 'red', label = 'Cycle End', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)    # Cycle End

axs[2].axvline(0,-1,len(df1),color='grey', label = 'Calendar Year Start / End',linewidth = 2, zorder = 1)   # put vertical line at Day 0 of calendar year
axs[2].axvline(365,-1,len(df1),color='grey', linewidth = 2, zorder = 1) # put vertical line at Day 365 of calendar year

##
#   plot the Period and Price data
#       
#       - blue horizontal line shows cycles that start and end in same calendar year
#       - orange horizontal line show cycles that either start in a previous calendar year, or end in the following calendar year.
#       - purple plot shows cycles that start and end in same calendar year
#       - black plot show cycles that either start in a previous calendar year, or end in the following calendar year.
##

for i in range(len(df)):#   Draw horizontal line(s) to show the cycle for each period / row in dataframe.

    ##  Option 1: Draw line between start and end points if start and end dates are in same calendar year (green marker to left of red).
    if df.loc[i,'Start'] < df.loc[i,'End']:
        axs[1].hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=df.loc[i,'Start'], xmax=df.loc[i,'End'], color='blue', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0) 
        
    ##  Option 2: Draw 2 lines if the start or end dates are not in the same calendar year (red marker to left of green).
    else:
        axs[1].hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=df.loc[i,'Start'], xmax=365, color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # end date is in next calendar year
        axs[1].hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=0, xmax=df.loc[i,'End'], color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # start date is in previous calendar year


if df1['Calendar Day'].iloc[0] < df1['Calendar Day'].iloc[-1]: # 'normal' where start and end are in same calendar year
        
    axs[2].plot(df1['Calendar Day'], df1['Price'], color='purple', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    

else:   # 'abnormal' where start and end are in different calendar years
    
    axs[1].scatter(df1['Calendar Day'],df1['Price'],color = 'black', marker = ',',s = 1, zorder = 2) 


if df2['Calendar Day'].iloc[0] < df2['Calendar Day'].iloc[-1]:  # 'normal' where start and end are in same calendar year
    
    axs[2].plot(df2['Calendar Day'], df2['Price'], color='black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)    # 
    
else:   # 'abnormal' where start and end are in different calendar years
    
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        
        print ('j = ',j, 'Calendar Day is: ',df2.loc[j,'Calendar Day'])
        
        if j>0 and (df2.loc[j,'Calendar Day'] < df2.loc[j-1,'Calendar Day']):   # determine split point
            
            split = j
            
    left_df = df2[:split]
    right_df = df2[split:]
    
    print ('Left DF\n',left_df) # for testing
    print ('Right DF\n',right_df)   # for testing
    
    axs[2].plot(left_df['Calendar Day'],left_df['Price'],color = 'black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 2)
    axs[2].plot(right_df['Calendar Day'],right_df['Price'],color = 'black', linewidth = 2, zorder = 2) 


plt.show()
```